# C#: How to traverse all elements from a nested list, with variable nesting and variable type?

Tags: c#, generics, multidimensional-array, nested

I want to create a function

```
void StringFromNestedList<T>(T theList);
```

theList could be of types such as

```
List<List<List<List<double>>>>
List<List<int>>
List<List<List<SomeCustomType>>>
```

and so on.

Let's assume for each element, I want to activate a function all elements are assumed to have, such as `ToString()`

If I knew the amount of nesting, and size of each list, for example 2 levels of 4 elements each, I would do something like

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++)
    {
        theList[i][j].ToString(); // yes, it doesnt really do anything
    }
}
```

But I don't know how many for loops are required.

Is it doable?

Comment: Is it always a List nested, or can it be any IEnumerable?

Comment: What should happens at the end? Just `ToString`? Then simply check if current item is `IEnumerable` and enumerate it. Recursively.

Comment: @Sinatr obviously something would happen, I wanted to dumb it down for the question

Comment: @ZoharPeled Can assume it is always a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure trying to make it generic will gain you anything.

So, first assume that it'll just take an `object`.

```
void StringFromPossibleList(object theList)
```

Now, assume we don't want to deal with lists but with anything enumerable. Assume further that we've already got this function working - then for each item inside our enumerable, we can just call ourselves recursively!

```
{
    var enu = theList as IEnumerable;
    if(enu!=null)
    {
        foreach(var item in enu)
        {
            StringFromPossibleList(item);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        theList.ToString();
    }
}
```

By using recursion, we get as many levels of looping as it turns out we need.

Comment: or shorter, using `is` - `if(theList is IEnumerable enu){....} else { theList?.ToString() }`...

Answer (score 0):

An alternative iterative solution could be something like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<object> FlattenNestedLists(object obj)
    {
        var stack = new Stack();
        stack.Push(obj);
        while (stack.Count > 0)
        {
            var current = stack.Pop();
            if (current is IEnumerable list)
            {
                foreach (var item in list)
                {
                    stack.Push(item);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                yield return current;
            }
        }
    }
```

The primary advantage would be that the objects are returned, and can be processed by something else. A downside is potential boxing, you could avoid this an additional check, but you will need to consider the behavior if lists contain dissimilar objects.